# Python replacing an specific word in a line

Tags: python

I have an aplication in flask , where I'm reading two colors, but when I try to replace them it deletes me everything in my .txt file but the lines that I'm trying to replace.

Here's my python file:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,flash,request,redirect
import os
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

def word_one():
    with open('line.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
          if i == 6: 
            found_color = line.find('color')
            if found_color != -1:
               color_one = line[found_color+len('color:'):]
               print ('Color_One: '), color_one
    return color_one


def word_two():
    with open('line.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
          if i == 7: 
            found_color = line.find('color')
            if found_color != -1:
               color_two = line[found_color+len('color:'):]
               print ('Color_Two: '), color_two
    return color_two

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def change_line():
    error= 'Sucessfull.'
    first_color = word_one()
    second_color = word_two()
    try:
        if request.method =="POST":
            change_first_color = request.form ['first_color']
            change_second_color = request.form['second_color']
            filedata= None
            with open('line.txt','r') as f:
                filedata = f.readlines()

                filedata[6] = filedata[6].replace(first_color , change_first_color + "\n" )
                filedata[7] = filedata[7].replace(second_color , change_second_color + "\n" )

            with open('line.txt','w') as f:
                f.write(filedata[6])
                f.write(filedata[7])


    except BaseException as e:
        print e
    return render_template('line.html', error=error, change_first_color=change_first_color,
                            change_second_color=change_second_color)

@app.route('/')
def showLine():
    change_first_color = word_one()
    change_second_color = word_two()
    return render_template('line.html', change_first_color=change_first_color,
                            change_second_color=change_second_color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is my text file :

```
/////
/////
/////
////
/////
/////////
    color green
    color green
```

As you can see I want to replace "green" to yellow and the other "green" to red, but when doing so it deletes every "/" in the file leaving just the last 2 lines.

Can anyone help me with this problem? **thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's expected:

```
    with open('line.txt','r') as f:
        filedata = f.readlines()

        filedata[6] = filedata[6].replace(first_color , change_first_color + "\n" )
        filedata[7] = filedata[7].replace(second_color , change_second_color + "\n" )

    with open('line.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(filedata[6])
        f.write(filedata[7])
```

You change lines 6 and 7 of `filedata`, you open/truncate the file again and just write both lines. droping the rest.

In your case, the fix is simple. Since you have changed the array of lines according to your need, just write back the full lines, modified with your changes. So change that last part into:

```
        with open('line.txt','w') as f:
            f.writelines(filedata)
```